# Windows-7, Windows Explorer -- Find all files in folders not named debug

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, search, find

Is there an easy was in Windows-7, Windows-Explorer to find all files named .dll in folders *not* named debug?

I would hope the answer would be somewhat consistent across Windows systems, but that might be too much to expect ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any Windows version with PowerShell, try the following:

`# initialize the items variable with the contents of a directory`

`$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\ProgramData\Notepad++" -Recurse`

`foreach ($item in $items)`

`{`

`if (($item.Attributes -ne "Directory") -and ($item.Name -like "*.dll") -and -not ($item.Directory -like "*ebug*"))`

`{ Write-Host $item.Name }`

`}`

**N.B** This code is poorly formatted and may need to be improved to work for your needs. Any help on it's appearance is welcome!